# How to update a single field from modal form in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, modal-dialog

I have a form that keeps track of when people enter/leave different areas. Whenever there is a discrepancy, for example, someone forgets to "leave" an area before entering a new one, the user is prompted an "estimate" of the time they believe they left the previous area at(**edited_timestamp**). The only two required fields on the main form are the employee number and the work area, as these are used to verify/keep track of data.

When I try to reproduce the situation that would make the modal show up, it works, but when I attempt to submit it, I get these messages:

[image: 1]

and these are the errors that are being returned.
[image: 2]]

Now, while I don't understand why the "Enter valid date/time" error is showing, I'm guessing the other two errors are due to the main form requiring the employee_number and the work_area and probably for this request, even though it is updating by the ID, it still wants the other two fields.

*I guess my question is, how could I modify this so that these two fields are not required for the modal?*

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
   station_number = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
    edited_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_exceptions = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, default='', choices=EXCEPTION_STATUS)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Time in", null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, help_text="Time out", null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number', 'edited_timestamp')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),
    url(r'update-timestamp-modal/(?P<main_pk>\d+)/$', UpdateTimestampModal.as_view(), name='update_timestamp_modal'),
]
```

(Took out leave_area code for redundancy)

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    form = WarehouseForm()
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        temp = request.POST.copy()
        form = WarehouseForm(temp)
        if form.is_valid():
            emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
            area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
            station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

            if 'enter_area' in request.POST:
                new_entry = form.save()
                EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)) & (Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True))).update(time_in=datetime.now())

                # If employee has an entry without an exit and attempts to enter a new area, mark as an exception 'N', meaning they're getting the modal
                enters_without_exits = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_exceptions="")).exclude(pk=new_entry.pk).order_by("-time_in")
                if len(enters_without_exits) > 0:
                    enter_without_exit = enters_without_exits[0]
                    enters_without_exits.update(time_exceptions='N')

                message = 'You have entered %(area)s' % {'area': area}
                if station is not None:
                    message += ': %(station)s' % {'station': station}
                messages.success(request, message)

    form = WarehouseForm()
    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'enter_without_exit': enter_without_exit,
    })


class UpdateTimestampModal(CreateUpdateModalView):
    main_model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    model_name = "EmployeeWorkAreaLog"
    form_class = WarehouseForm
    template = 'operations/modals/update_timestamp_modal.html'
    modal_title = 'Update Missing Time'
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load core_tags staticfiles %}

{% block head %}
    <script src="{% static "js/operations/warehouse_enter_exit.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock head %}

{% block main %}

    {% if enter_without_exit %}
        <div id="auto-open-ajax-modal" data-modal="#create-update-modal" data-modal-url="{% url "operations:update_timestamp_modal" enter_without_exit.id %}" class="hidden"></div>
    {% endif %}

    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <div style="color: red">{{ form.employee_number.errors.as_text }}</div>
                <label>Employee</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>

            <div>
                <div style="color: red">{{ form.work_area.errors.as_text }}</div>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div style="color: red">{{ form.station_number.errors.as_text }}</div>
            <div>
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    {% modal id="create-update-modal" title="Update Timestamp" primary_btn="Submit" default_submit=True %}
```

**update_timestamp_modal.html**

```
{% load core_tags %}

<form id="create-update-form" method="post" action="{% url "operations:update_timestamp_modal" main_object.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label>Update</label>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                {% standard_input form.edited_timestamp datetimepicker=True hide_label=True %}
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**warehouse_enter_exit.js**

```
$(function () {
    // Submit the edited timestamp form when they click the "Submit" button in the modal
    $(document).on('click', '#update-timestamp-modal-btn-primary', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        forms.ajaxSubmit($('#create-update-form'), function (data) {
            if (data.success && data.redirect) {
                window.location.href = data.redirect;
            } else {
                if (data.warning) {
                    messages.warning(data.warning);
                } else {
                    messages.error("An error occurred when saving this timestamp, please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Could I maybe edit the JS to only update the edited_timestamp field? Or maybe a way I can edit the views so that only that ID is accessed to update that field? The URL to the modal access it based on ID so I thought there could be a way to edit only based on this field.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override those fields in your form code. 
Like this:

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    employee_number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.all(), required=False)
    work_area = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta...
```

Comment: Even if they’re ForeignKeys in the model I can do this? For example, employee_number is a ForeignKey that uses integers as input, would I still use the CharField or one for integers?

Comment: Sorry, you can use a IntegerField, I'll edit my answer!

Comment: This creates a problem with the widget since employee_number needs to be cross checked with another model (that’s why it is a foreignkey) therefore it kinda removes the foreignkey purpose

Comment: Which version of Django you're using?

Comment: For a model form with foreign keys, Django tells you to use ModelChoiceField in your form, check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield